# Update open google maps Infowindow

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, infowindow

I am playing round with getting json information from a bus tracker website and rolling my own with google maps, obviously not as pretty. 
Currently I can’t figure out how to update an infowindow while it is open. I found some examples but nothing seems to work for what I want. I somehow managed to get the markers to update and move for each “update” but the info windows do not do what I want. I want to be able to click on a marker and have it list, say vehicle speed in the infowindow. While the window is still open and the json updates/downloads, the marker will move and I want the content of the window to also update with the new speed. That is have an open infowindow update its content without closing it.

Bonus: the goal is to have the runbuses() function be toggle on and off with a checkbox. So that when it is unchecked it stops downloading new json. I also don’t have any idea how to do that. Haha

Anyway this has been fun while trying to learn a little java. 
Thanks!

```js
function runbuses() {
  setInterval(function() {

    loadbus(map)

  }, 5000);
}


function loadbus(map) {

  //howardshuttle.com

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.howardshuttle.com/Services/JSONPRelay.svc/GetMapVehiclePoints",
    data: 'ApiKey=8882812681',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'method',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(obj) {

      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

        var image = {
          url: setumicon(obj[i]['Heading']),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
        }

        console.log(obj[i].Name);

        //Do we have this marker already?
        if (umbuses.hasOwnProperty(obj[i].Name)) {
          umbuses[obj[i].Name].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Latitude, obj[i].Longitude));
          umbuses[obj[i].Name].setIcon(image);

   // How do i update the info window that is open?


          console.log(Math.round(obj[i]['GroundSpeed']));
          console.log('has prop');

        } else {
          var hover = obj[i].Name;
          console.log('new');
          var image = {
            url: setumicon(obj[i].Heading),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40)
          }

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i].Latitude, obj[i].Longitude),
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: String(hover)
          });


          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {

              if (activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();

              uminfo.setContent("<p>" + obj[i]['Name'] + "<br />" + umFindroute(obj[i]['RouteID']) + "<br />" +
                "Speed: " + Math.round(obj[i]['GroundSpeed']) + " mph" + "</p>");


              uminfo.open(map, marker);
              activeInfoWindow = uminfo;

            }
          })(marker, i));


          umbuses[obj[i].Name] = marker;
          console.log(umbuses);

        }

      }


    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("some error");
    }

  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the content of an open InfoWindow, give the HTML element in it that you what to change an id and use HTML DOM manipulation to change it.

```
uminfo.setContent("<div id='infowin'><p>" + obj[i]['Name'] + "<br />" + umFindroute(obj[i]['RouteID']) + "<br />" +
            "Speed: " + Math.round(obj[i]['GroundSpeed']) + " mph" + "</p></div>");
```

Then if the InfoWindow is open, this should work:

```
document.getElementById('infowin').innerHTML = "<p>" + obj[i]['Name'] + "<br />" + umFindroute(obj[i]['RouteID']) + "<br />" +
            "Speed: " + Math.round(obj[i]['GroundSpeed']) + " mph" + "</p>";
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter()
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<div id='infowin'>original content</div>"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  })
  google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  setInterval(function() {
    marker.setPosition(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(marker.getPosition(), 100, 90));
    document.getElementById('infowin').innerHTML = "<b>Time</b>:" + Date() + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
  }, 5000);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I get it a little better now. I got it mostly working for my code but ran into two problems. It will error if a info window is not open - I think I can figure this out. The second is how to get it to work with multiple markers. It will use the information for whatever the last object in the json is. only thing I can think of is get the title of a selected marker and use that to match json? I dont know..

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). For your additional issues: 1. check to see if the element exists before trying to change it (means it isn't open, or hasn't been rendered yet), 2. it should just work for multiple markers, as long as you only have one InfoWindow open at a time (and you handle the case where it isn't opened yet).  If you have issues making that work, that is another question.